# WebClient Download exceptions - 405 & timeout.

Tags: c#, content-disposition, http-status-code-405, webclient

I'm using a simple webClient to download some images from the web. THis process works well for the majority of cases, however i'm getting a few errors for a few images that I'm trying.

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.DownloadFile(orig_file, filePath);
```

http://www.robertdyas.co.uk/sites/rdmainv4.57/productimages/500x500f/162234.jpg
 - The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

http://www.moneysupermarket.com/deals/CampaignImage/Detail/9995?width=615&height=335
 - receive a timeout exception
 - this contains a "Content-Disposition: attachment;" header which auto downloads the file when image is viewed in a browser.

Any insight as to how I can get around the above issues would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you own any of these sites?

Comment: no, these are two random site images selected at random used to test the code

Comment: @user2008865 - Its entirely possible the server configuration of these servers prevent this type of download.  How large are these files I have noticed there is a size limit/timeout built into WebClient.

Comment: 25.4KB and 44.4KB respectively. If it is a server configuration that is stopping the download of these files directly, is there any way around this (with webclient or alternative)?